# How to build a Maven Project in Jenkins using Test-Ng xml file instead of POM xml?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

Usually, we configure the POM.xml in Build Environment and then run/build project in Jenkins but how do I do the same using Test-NG.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by adding Maven Surefire Plugin property in to POM.XML,

Reference Example:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>

            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>                     
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```